# How to create ((E1 AND E2) OR (E3 AND E4)) AND E5 expression in QueryDSL

Tags: querydsl

How to create below expression in QueryDSL

```
((E1 AND E2) OR (E3 AND E4)) AND E5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply: `e1.and(e2).or(e3.and(e4)).and(e5)`. It will serialize as `E1 AND E2 OR (E3 AND E4) AND E5` but that is not a problem as `AND` and `OR` share the same precedence and are evaluated left to right (in JPQL, see for example https://openjpa.apache.org/builds/1.2.3/apache-openjpa/docs/jpa_langref.html#jpa_langref_operators).